# Perl OO Question, Inheritance - calling parent method

Tags: perl, perl-module

Why am I not able to call testmethod of parent using child object in the following code?

```perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $a = C::Main->new('Email');
$a->testmethod();

package C::Main;


sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $type  = shift;
    $class .= "::" . $type;
    my $fmgr = bless {}, $class;
    $fmgr->init(@_);
    return $fmgr;
}

sub init {
    my $fmgr = shift;
    $fmgr;
}

sub testmethod {
    print "SSS";
}

package C::Main::Email;
use Net::FTP;

@C::Main::Email::ISA = qw( C::Main );

sub init {
    my $fmgr = shift;
    my $ftp = $fmgr->{ftp} = Net::FTP->new( $_[0] );
    $fmgr;
}

package C::Main::FTP;
use strict;
use Net::FTP;

@C::Main::Email::FTP = qw( C::Main );

sub init {
    my $fmgr = shift;
    $fmgr;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to keep repeating `use strict;` in each package. Since `strict` is a lexically scoped pragma, it is in effect until the current scope ends.  Package declarations do not create a scope, so if `use strict;` is placed at the top of a file, it is in scope for the entire file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because assignment into `@ISA` is done at runtime, thus after you try to call the method.

You can make it work by surrounding by `BEGIN`, moving it to compile time:

```
BEGIN { our @ISA = qw( C::Main ) }
```

or you can do

```
use base qw( C::Main );
```

which is also done in compile time. Both variants do fix your problem.

Comment: I concur, however, from what I read, `use parent ...` is now preferred over `use base ...`.

Comment: @Joel - I heard that `base` has some problems and somehow is trying to solve too much, although I never used it for anything else than inheritance. `parent` also came core in 5.10.1, at least according to `Module::CoreList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing new OO code in Perl, use Moose!

Returning to 'use base' after having used Moose is like going back to the 1950s.